# Can "used to" be a verb?

Tags: verbs, infinitives

In the sentence:

> I **used to** hurt people.

*to hurt* is an infinitive. I read somewhere that infinitives are not verbs. So can *used to* be a verb? If not, should we treat ***used to*** as one entity which describes the past and take ***hurt*** as a verb?

Comment: How can you take 'to hurt' , if you want to consider 'used to' in your sentence ?

Comment: @RuchirM its "to hurt" or "used to". i dont know which one is right.

Comment: A dictionary clearly defines *[used to](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/used-to_1)* in this sense as a modal verb.

Comment: why double question mark every time ??

Answer (score 2):

In your sentence, 'used to' is used as a modal verb. Check [OALD.](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/used-to?q=used%20to)

As 'used to' itself show that something happened continuously or frequently in the past, hurt is a transitive verb here.

So, IMO, in your sentence 'hurt' is not an infinitive, but verb.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

The main misconception here is that *a verb* and *an infinitive* are mutually exclusive. According to LDOCE definition an [infinitive](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/infinitive) is:

> the **basic form of a verb**, used with 'to' in English

(emphasis mine).

In addition to this definition, when *to* is omitted we get a *bare infinitive*.

So, in your example both *used to* and *hurt* are verbs, but in different forms.

Answer (score 1):

**we should treat *used to* as one entity which describes the past and take hurt as a verb**.

Moreover, from [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/used-to_1):

- Used to is usually followed by an infinitive
- Used to only exists as a past tense. So one cannot say, *'I use to heart people'*